# Trigger createOrder function (Paypal SDK) via typescript

Tags: angular, paypal, paypal-buttons

I am using  `window.paypal.Buttons()` in an Angular 12 page.
I created a Paypal component where there is only the Paypal button:
**paypal.components.html**

```
<div id="paypal-button-container" #paypalButton></div>
```

**paypal.components.ts**

```
  @ViewChild('paypalButton') paypalButton: ElementRef;
  ngOnInit(): void {
    window.paypal.Buttons({
      style: {
        layout: 'horizontal',
        color: 'white',
        shape: 'rect',
        label: 'paypal'
      },
      createOrder: async (data, actions) => {
        //create order using Orders API
      },
      onApprove: async (data, actions) => {
        //capture payment using Orders API
      },
      onError: (data, actions) => {
        console.log("do stuff")
      }
    }).render('#paypal-button-container');
```

I would like to give the user the possibility to start the payment flow by clicking paypal button, or clicking a more generic "PAY" button (since I implemented other payment strategies too).
So I need to access the `onApprove()` method from the parent component.
I tried the following code but it doesn't seem to be activated by `click()`:
**parent.components.ts**

```
  //the above component
  @ViewChild('paypal') paypalComponent: PaypalComponent;

  //called when clicking a general "PAY" button in the parent component
  checkout(): void {
    if (this.paymentMethod === "paypal") this.paypalComponent.paypalButton.nativeElement.click();
  }
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? The JS SDK renders an HTML button component. It is intended to be seen and clicked by a human user. If you don't want to render a button for a user to click themselves, don't use the JS SDK. Use the v2/checkout/orders API to create an order which will give back a URL for approval

Comment: (when creating an order, specify a return_url which should show a review step before capturing. You can optionally skip showing a review step; if this is what you are going to do, set the application_context.user_action to PAY_NOW; see the API reference for details)

Comment: @PrestonPHX
Thank you!
I've only seen in the docs the API being called with the JS SDK, so I thought that calling it manually was bad practice.
`createorder()` and `onApprove` functions make some calls to my server that calls the orders API after some security checks, so are you saying that I can safely move that logic to the parent components and don't use the SDK components at all?

Comment: That's too vague of a question, what to use depends on what you are trying to accomplish. The rest is implementation details.

Answer (score 0):

The [PayPal JavaScript SDK](https://developer.paypal.com/sdk/js/reference/) ([demo here](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client)) is only useful to render one or more UI buttons for a user to click on.

If your intention is not to render UI buttons, but rather perform operations... for instance obtain an approval link, then use the rest API from your server, e.g. [create an order](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#orders_create). A created order will have a link with rel:approve. After approval by a user on some device they will be directed to the provided return_url for you to show a final review step. The order will then need to be captured after which the success or failure can be shown.

---

There is some [angular-specific information for the JS SDK buttons here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/customize/single-page-app/), if rendering payment button(s) is what you want to do. Typically it is, since angular is a front-end framework.

Comment: I edited my question, I hope it's now more clear!
I need to have an UI Paypal button that starts the payment flow. I've already implemented the OrderAPI and the button works fine if clicked by the user.  
I would also like to start the same flow by pressing another button in the parent component.

If I correctly understood I have to perform different calls to the OrderAPI and manually build the payment flow and I can't trigger SDK buttons functions via DOM

Comment: You should render two separate buttons (each with their own containers), and have them both invoke the same (single, shared) createOrder and onApprove functions.